# What does const mean?

Tags: angular, dart

I am using angular2dart and want to know, why do I have to pass keyword const on:

```
directives: const [HeroDetailComponent]
```

component properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`const` means a compile-time constant. Been constant it can be optimized and instantiated only once.

`const [HeroDetailComponent]` means that the list is a compile time constant. Compile-time constants are mandatory when used as [metadata](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#metadata) (in your case `directives` is a named parameter of `@Component()` that is a metadata of your class).

Comment: See the link on the answer ;) TL;DR it's like annotation in other langages.